# Running bvlc-caffe docker image as non-root user results in unexpected NVCC flags

Tags: linux, docker, caffe

Host OS: `ubuntu 14.04`
GPU Model: `Tesla K80`
Cuda Driver: `352.93`
Docker image: [bvlc/caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/docker/standalone/gpu/Dockerfile)

Based on upper stuff, we tried to run `cd /opt/caffe/build && make runtest` inside a bvlc/caffe container and then succeeded to see all test cases PASSED.

However, after we slightly modified the bvlc/caffe image using following shell commands:

`echo "dastan ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers`
`useradd dastan && adduser dastan sudo`
`mkdir -p /home/dastan && chown -R dastan:dastan /home/dastan`

Then ran as `dastan`(non-root user) and `cd /opt/caffe/build; sudo make runtest`, we got `CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version` in the test cases.

I compared the pre-compiling messages under both `root` and `dastan`(non-root) scenarios, and finally found out that `CUDA NVCC flags` under `root` was `sm_37`, while under `non-root` it became `sm_20 sm_21 sm_30 sm_35 sm_50` with message `Automatic GPU detection failed. Building for all known architectures.`

Can anybody explains: what's really different under root and non-root for CUDA?

Comment: Each user has a separate environment setting. People generally don't use root account to do non-administrative operations. You may need a full tutorial on Linux administration and user management.

Comment: @kangshiyin I expect that `sudo` can work as well as `root` but it doesn't. This is what really confuse me.

Comment: sudo may use a different environment setting from root (e.g. $PATH).